# Issues outputting strings vs lists from CSV

Tags: python, csv

So I have the below code that's meant to take a CSV file of 4 columns, add in one or two pipes (for MediaWiki table formatting), and spit them out ready for copy/paste usage.

```
import csv

with open("example.csv", 'r') as CSVfile:
    for row in csv.reader(CSVfile):
        row[0] = "|" + str(row[0])
        row[1] = "||" + str(row[1])
        row[2] = "||" + str(row[2])
        row[3] = "||" + str(row[3])
        f = open("finished.txt", "a")
        ', '.join(row)
        f.write(str(row))
```

The input looks like the following:

```
Advertising,Mobile phone App,Coupon,Android
```

And when I refer to the outputted contents, it appears as so:

```
['|Advertising', '||Mobile phone App', '||Coupon', '||Android']
```

Now it's quite likely that I've simply gone about the goal terribly with the above code, but I'd like to know how best to output without the brackets, commas, and apostrophes.

Comment: the line `', '.join(row)` by itself will not modify the `row` list. So you should either do `row = ', '.join(row)` or use mu's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your `f.write` statement. As it currently stands, you are writing the string representation of the row, which happens to be a list, and not the join of it in to the file. Though you have done a `join` on the string, the row remains unaffected.

```
f.write(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: Fantastic. Two for one, and one less line of code. Any thoughts on how to get rid of the commas that remain?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe I assumed you needed the commas, since they were there in your original post. Anyway, just do `f.write(' '.join(row))` and that should work.

Comment: One again you beat me in elegance. I had come up with f.write(', '.join(row).replace(',','')). Thanks again!